# Should we merge the tags [concert] and [live-music]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

A concert is a live music performance, so having both [concert](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concert) and [live-music](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-music) seems redundant. So, I propose that we merge both tags.

Specifically, I suggest we make [concert](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concert) a synonym of [live-music](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-music), because there are different names given for a live music performance such as concert, recital, show, gig, etc. [as mentioned by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concert) but they are all essentially the same topic, namely a [live-music](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-music) performance.

Currently the stats are as follows:

- 15 questions tagged only [concert](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concert) (3 unanswered)
- 22 questions tagged only [live-music](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-music) (1 unanswered)
- 5 questions tagged with both (1 unanswered)

Comment: 100% agree, live-music should be the master.

Comment: I'm not sure I personally agree with this. Yes there is a huge overlap, but I'd think concert is more about the history of concert performances while live music is more about going to or hearing a live performance. One example I'd give is if I asked "How many times did Chris Cornell and Eddie Vedder perform hunger strike together in concert?" where live music makes sense, but concert really gets to the point of what the question is asking.

Comment: As someone who works in live music as both a performer and sound engineer, I feel like they are different. For example, you would ask someone "How was the concert you went to last night?" rather than "How was the live music you hear last night?". There is also a lot more that goes into a concert than just music. The venue, choreography, personnel,  and visuals go into it make it very unique. The music is part of it, but one of many aspects. You can also do something like street preforming that is live, but not a concert. There is overlap, but I don't see them as quite the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags were merged by @JohnnyBones on 2019-3-28, with [live-music](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-music) kept as the master tag and [concert](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concert) as its synonym. See the [tag synonyms](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) page for reference.

Answer (score 0):

After considering @Dom's arguments and carefully reading these words' definitions, I think that these are two different tags and shouldn't be merged. - @Bebs

---

*Since [comments are ephemereal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174), it might be better to pull down @Dom's comments into this CW answer:* - @Brahadeesh

> I'm not sure I personally agree with this. Yes there is a huge overlap, but I'd think concert is more about the history of concert performances while live music is more about going to or hearing a live performance. One example I'd give is if I asked "How many times did Chris Cornell and Eddie Vedder perform hunger strike together in concert?" where live music makes sense, but concert really gets to the point of what the question is asking. – [Dom♦](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7/dom) [Mar 18 '19 at 16:15](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/475/should-we-merge-the-tags-concert-and-live-music#comment1023_475)
>
> As someone who works in live music as both a performer and sound engineer, I feel like they are different. For example, you would ask someone "How was the concert you went to last night?" rather than "How was the live music you hear last night?". There is also a lot more that goes into a concert than just music. The venue, choreography, personnel, and visuals go into it make it very unique. The music is part of it, but one of many aspects. You can also do something like street preforming that is live, but not a concert. There is overlap, but I don't see them as quite the same thing. – [Dom♦](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7/dom) [Mar 18 '19 at 19:52](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/475/should-we-merge-the-tags-concert-and-live-music#comment1025_475)